# How to initialize template10 infrastructure to start application

Tags: c#, uwp, template10

Good Day,

Im having an issue with https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10

on My View lets say I have a textbox and its text property is bound to my VM(Note: My VM inherited BindableBase from template10:

```
private string _sampleText;
    public string SampleText {
        get { return _sampleText; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref _sampleText, value); }
    }
```

but every time I input a text on my text box Im having a *null reference Exception from RaisePropertyChanged*

I think I need to instialize template10 using BootStrapper on my app.xaml.cs

How is that?

Thanks

Comment: There is no extra initialization of the framework other than the basic setup. Have you looked at the samples? What template are you using (Minimal, Blank or Hamburger)?

Comment: Yes yes I found out that all you need is to install the template10 template pack

Comment: be careful not to confuse the Master repository with nuget available.  Master = T10.2 where as nuget is 10.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching  found out that you just need to install template10 template pack: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jerry-nixon.Template10TemplatePack

then just select template10 template then its all set
please see image attached:
[image]